# How increase height dynamically by fixing width of the rect box in d3 js

Tags: json, html, d3.js

I'm using d3 js for collapsing tree.
I want to fix the width of the rectangle.
If text size in rectangle box is more than the fixed width of rect box how to increase height of rect box dynamically?

Like below image I want the output.
[image]

Here is the code what I'm using

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 10px 4px 20px;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }
 
 .node rect {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A. Some text here Some text here Some text here",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B",
        "parent": "Top Level"
  
      }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);


var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.source.x,
                "y": d.source.y + 150
            };
        })
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y + 0, d.x + 0];
      });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", 60)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -15 : -15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 150)
     .attr("height", 30)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
   .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", 10);

  nodeExit.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a superficial attempt.

1. First add all the text elements
2. Wrap the text element within certain width using tspans
3. Get the height of the text element and store as an attribute it in the data itself
4. Use the stored attribute for setting the height of the rectangle

Reference for wrapping text [here](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321). You can always write custom wrapping function.

Hope this helps

```js
var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A. Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A Some text here Some text here",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here Some text here",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B Some text here Some text here Some text here",
        "parent": "Top Level"
  
      }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);


var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.source.x,
                "y": d.source.y + 150
            };
        })
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y + 0, d.x + 0];
      });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", 60)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
     .each(function(d) {
       calculateTextWrap(this,d);
    });

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -15 : -15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 150)
     .attr("height", function(d) { return d.rectHeight})
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
   .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", 10);

  nodeExit.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

 function calculateTextWrap(element, data) {
                    var text = d3.select(element);
                    if (text.node().getComputedTextLength() < 150) {
                        //console.log("No need to wrap");
                    } else {
                        var words = text.text().split("").reverse(),
                            word,
                            line = [],
                            lineNumber = 0,
                            lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
                            y = text.attr("y"),
                            dy = parseFloat(0.35),
                            tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("text-anchor", "start").attr("x", 5).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");

                        while (word = words.pop()) {
                            line.push(word);
                            tspan.text(line.join(""));
                            if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > 150) {
                                lineNumber++;
                                line.pop();
                                tspan.text(line.join(""));
                                line = [word];
                                tspan = text.append("tspan").attr("text-anchor", "start").attr("x", 5).attr("y", y).attr("dy", lineHeight + dy + "em").text(word);
                            }
                        }
                    }
    var rectHeight = text.node().getBBox().height;
     if(rectHeight < 30) rectHeight = 30;
    data.rectHeight = rectHeight + 10 ;
                }
 
 
  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}
```

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 10px 4px 20px;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }
 
 .node rect {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your styling :

```
.node {
  height: fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: .5rem;
}
```

It fits the height and size of the node class to the content (text) of the element. It should do the trick.