# Adjust rectangle node size (width & height of the node) by size of the text dynamically using d3 js

Tags: html, d3.js

I'm using D3 js for collapse tree.
I want to adjust node size(width & height) by size of the text.

In below diagram you can see size of rect nodes varying with size of the text

[image]

Here is the code I'm using

Please help me out on this

```css
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-style: solid;
    border-width: 2px 10px 4px 20px;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }
 
 .node rect {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }
```

```html
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
 
<script>

var treeData = [
  {
    "name": "Top Level",
    "parent": "null",
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "Level 2: A",
        "parent": "Top Level",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "Son of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          },
          {
            "name": "Daughter of A",
            "parent": "Level 2: A"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "Level 2: B some text some text some text some text some text",
        "parent": "Top Level"
  
      }
    ]
  }
];


// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
 width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
 height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
var i = 0,
 duration = 750,
 root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
 .size([height, width]);


var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
        .source(function (d) {
            return {
                "x": d.source.x,
                "y": d.source.y + 150
            };
        })
        .projection(function (d) { return [d.y + 0, d.x + 0];
      });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
 .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
 .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;
  
update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
   links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
   .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", 10)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", 60)
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -15 : -15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 150)
     .attr("height", 30)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1)
.attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
   .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 0 : 0; })
  .attr("y", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? 15 : 15; })
  .attr("rx", 10)
  .attr("ry", 10)
     .attr("width", 10)
     .attr("height", 10);

  nodeExit.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6)
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle");

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
   .attr("class", "link")
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "black")
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
   .duration(duration)
   .attr("d", function(d) {
  var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
  return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
   })
   .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
 d._children = d.children;
 d.children = null;
  } else {
 d.children = d._children;
 d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

</script>
```

Comment: you only asked this question I guess ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40415676/how-increase-height-dynamically-by-fixing-width-of-the-rect-box-in-d3-js

Comment: Here I want to customize both length and width. So that each node can be of different sizes. And Also connecting point is not in center of the node when height is increased in previous

Comment: Is it possible in d3 js to adjust node width and height? Can any one helped me out on this.... Thanks in advance

Comment: It is possible. I will try to answer when I am free. Idea is to calculate the text width and height. That can be done by using getboundbox method(not sure about the spelling)

Comment: I tried but not able to do it. Can you post the code for it. Thanks in advance....
I want some thing like this using D3 js https://gojs.net/latest/samples/DOMTree.html